# How can I transform this div without transforming the image within?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I tried to make a shape using `div` and put an image inside. I want the image to maintain its default shape (rectangle or square) without skewing, but when I put image inside, the image skewed with the `div`. For the `div` shape I am using `transform: skewY(-10deg);`

```css
.intro {
  width: 180px;
  height: 400px;
  /* border-radius:50%;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  margin: 35px 35px 35px 0px;
}
.intro img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/400/sports">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to accomplish this: distort the shape of the outer object but keep the inner shape the same. The only way to do that is to `transform` the inner shape by the *negative* of the outer shape `transform` (aka, if your `skewY(10deg)` on the outer shape, do `skewY(-10deg)` on the inner), then hiding the `overflow`.

See this snippet:

```css
.intro {
    width: 180px;
    height: 400px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    /* I added the -webkit- prefix as I'm using Safari 8 and
     * it wouldn't show up otherwise. Might want to prefix that! */
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-10deg);
    transform: skewY(-10deg);
    margin: 35px 35px 35px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.intro img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(10deg);
    transform: skewY(10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/400/sports">
</div>
```

An annoying sideeffect of this is that your contents will seem cut off. The only way to solve that is to make the inner shape larger than the outer shape an potentially padding the inside. For your image, I'd suggest:

```
.intro { 
    position: relative;
}
.intro img {
    /* Use min width and heights higher than 100% 
     * (you might need to experiment here as it depends
     *  on the angle you chose for your skew) to fill
     *  the outer shape completely. */
    min-width: 110%;
    min-height: 110%;
    /* Position the element absolute and 50%
     * from the top and left */
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    /* Now add a transform to it to move it with 
     * half of its width and height, therefore centering it. */
    -webkit-transform: skewY(10deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: skewY(10deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Now you could also do `width: 110%; height: 110%; left: -5%; top: -5%;` and it would accomplish similar results. Play around with it.

#### Update

As per @vals suggestion, it might be a lot simpeler to just use the `scale` transform instead of all the positioning mumbo jumbo. Its always the simplest solution thats easiest to overlook:

```
.intro img {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(10deg) scale(1.2, 1.2);
    transform: skewY(10deg) scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
```

Comment: Also, you can solve the image being cut off using scale:  *transform: skewY(10deg) scale(1.1);* for the image. May be easier than doing it with min-width and so.

Comment: That _is_ better! I'll keep that in mind (and amend my post when i can/remember).